# Selenium Server - Google Captcha issue

Tags: selenium, remotewebdriver

I have Selenium Server running on a remote server, and on the same server I have a public-facing site configured in IIS that implements the RemoteWebDriver to run automated tests.

I am accessing the site from my local machine, and it's generally working fine.

One of the tests I have in place involves going to google.com and entering a search term. The problem I have is that each time I run the test,  Google shows the 'Unusual traffic from your computer network' Captcha page.

Can anyone recommend a way around this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have to tried clearing cookies before each test?

Comment: yeah tried that, no luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding the following parameter when launching the selenium server jar:

-Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=default

It appears that, by default, the Firefox remote WebDriver uses a new clean, anonymous profile. Google didn't like this. So the above forces it to use the existing 'default' firefox profile. At least that's my understanding anyway!